# Как выполнить цикл foreach до определенного индекса?

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

Как выполнить цикл foreach до определенного индекса? Например, до `1000-го`.

```
<?
  foreach($item as $items) {
   echo $items;
  }
?>
```

Comment: if(condition) break;

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($item as $key => $items) {
    if ($key == 3) {
        echo "Number $key was found!";
        break;
    } else {
        echo $items. PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: На самом деле это неверный ответ)) Потому что никто не сказал, что $key - числовой))

Comment: И `else` тут уже ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($item as $items) {
    if ($i == 1000) {
        echo "Index was found!";
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```